# Slider not moving automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a single page website but my slider is not automatically moving even after i am adding the script. I want my slider to move automatically. Please find the following HTML code below:

```
       <div id="slider" class="sl-slider-wrapper">

            <div class="sl-slider">

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-25" data-slice2-rotation="-25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="2">

                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-1"></div>

                    <div class="slide-caption">
                        <div class="caption-content">
                            <h2 class="animated fadeInDown">Lorem ipsum</h2>
                            <span class="animated fadeInDown">Lorem ipsum</span>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue btn-effect">Join US</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="10" data-slice2-rotation="-15" data-slice1-scale="1.5" data-slice2-scale="1.5">

                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-2"></div>
                    <div class="slide-caption">
                        <div class="caption-content">
                            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                            <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue btn-effect">Join US</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="3" data-slice2-rotation="3" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">

                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-3"></div>
                    <div class="slide-caption">
                        <div class="caption-content">
                            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                            <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue btn-effect">Join US</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div><!-- /sl-slider -->

            <!-- 
            <nav id="nav-arrows" class="nav-arrows">
                <span class="nav-arrow-prev">Previous</span>
                <span class="nav-arrow-next">Next</span>
            </nav>
            -->

            <nav id="nav-arrows" class="nav-arrows hidden-xs hidden-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="sl-prev">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="sl-next">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i>
                </a>
            </nav>


            <nav id="nav-dots" class="nav-dots visible-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                <span class="nav-dot-current"></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </nav>

        </div><!-- /slider-wrapper -->
```

I am also adding my script code which i tried to add. How can I find the appropriate script file so that my slider starts moving automatically after some interval?

Here is my script:

```
// Carousel Auto-Cycle
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.sl-slider-wrapper').sl-slider-wrapper({
              interval: 1000
            })
          });
```

Comment: you push one by one

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the devtools of your page while it's running? i'm sure it's throwing an error - the javascript inside the document ready function should read:

```
...
$('.sl-slider-wrapper').slitslider({
...
```

I think it's a copy/paste error in your javascript.